# Angular directive not replacing dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

i am creating a dynamic angular element on a new page as follows

Index.html

```
var openPrint = window.open('/acImageViewer/html/imageLibraries.html');
            openPrint.onload = function() {
                var doc = openPrint.document;
                $(doc.body).html('<jqyiviewer class="filter_icon_ul viewerHeight" id="acImgViewer" src="http://www.wellclean.com/wp-content/themes/artgallery_3.0/images/car3.png" align="centre" width="auto" height="500" data="data"></jqyiviewer>');
            };
```

this opens a new page where i have my libraries , directives and css loaded as follows (imageLibraries.html)

```
<html ng-app="acIViewerApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Image viewer</title>
<link href="/acImageViewer/css/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/new_kendo.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/jquery.iviewer.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../css/style.less" rel="stylesheet/less">


<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/less.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script><!--JQuery library-->
<script src="../libs/jquery-ui.min.js"></script><!--Jquery library -->
<script src="../libs/acImageViewer.js"></script><!--JQuery library for Imageviewer-->

<script src="../libs/kendo.all.min.js"></script><!--For Kendo Functionality -->

<script src="../libs/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script><!--JQuery library for use mouse event-->
<script src="../js/app.js"></script>

<script src="../js/directives/directives.js"></script><!--directive for iviewer-->

</head>

<body>


</body>
</html>
```

The body is getting dynamically generated in the index.html.
The problem is the directive.js is not replacing the jqyiviewer tag.

I am using the same tag in my index.html , here everything works fine.

I am guessing that my directive.js gets loaded and compiles 1st , after that the tag gets inserted , so it does not replace it.

Comment: you are using the wrong form of DOM manipulation using onload event to put the directive in the page, AngularJS does not allow you to do that, the directive has to be in the view

Comment: @SameerShemna yea not the best way to do it .. But how will angular handle a dynamically created element so it can can replace it with some directive ..

Comment: how will angular handle it? it will handle it as if were general text

Comment: Why isn't the directive tag in the file that gets loaded?

Comment: @charlietfl cause i need to set dynamic attributes such as 'src' then create the element on DOM. FYI: everything works fine if i directly include the tag in the body

Comment: could use postMessage API to pass data or manually bootstrap angular after inserting directive html

Comment: you need to $compile added html, not sure how to do this is new window thow